localhost from docker-compose
Подскажите как получить доступ по сервиса развернутого на 127.0.0.1 хостовой машины, из докера.
Если приложение на хостовой машине развернуто на IP 0.0.0.0, то способ обсуждаемый на
данном форуме подходит. Однако если сервис к которому нужно получить доступ размещен на 127.0.0.1, то тогда доступа нет. Подскажите возможные варианты решения.
